# How to update the UI after an asynchronous task in an extra class has finished using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

Hy!

I'd like to know what the best practice is to update the UI of an Android App with Kotlin once a Volley request has finished and the onResponse handler was called. The way I want to solve the Problem gives me some hard time, so maybe I have the wrong approach...

I come from a synchronous world and therefor my approach would be like this: Create a class that fetches the data and returns the fetched data. Once the function returned the data, update the UI.

We live in an asynchronous world however and therefor the approach must be different.

I still want the data fetching in an extra class. Doing the data fetching in the main class and updating the UI from within the onResponse eventlistener as shown in [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) is simple but can't be best practice, right? The data-fetching-class should not contain any reference to the UI, since it should be reusable.

How could it be done in a simple yet effective and reusable manner? Please elaborate with examples. Can it be done with something like async/await? Can it be done with something like a hook or an event listener (I'm thinking of socket.io). Could `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` help some way?

*I was looking this Topic up for hours, but I couldn't find anything useful. So either I'm looking in the wrong places, or the answer is so obvious that nobody asked it before. Some of the answers I found so far were very specific or contained so much extra code that i didn't find it useful.*

*As so many apps are doing just what I want to achieve, this must be an easy task. Any app fetching data from the internet needs exactly what I'm asking for. So I must be missing something.*

Thanks!

Comment: Using the `onResponse` is best practice for simple updates. If you dont want to update the UI directly use MVP or MVVM and update your model in the onRespone callback. The callback is executed on the UI-thread. If you want a more 'elaborate' way look into [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html)

Comment: But using ```onResponse``` for UI updates would force me to include the data-fetching-function in the main class which takes away a lot of reusability.

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/mvvm-architecture-viewmodel-and-livedata-part-1-604f50cda1

Comment: If you want it easy, do it this way. If you want it *nice* you have to learn how to use a pattern like MVVM correctly. There are many resources (including SO) that explain these pattern already. If you have more questions you should ask a new (specific) question instead of editing this one.

Answer (score 0):

**First part:**

> As so many apps are doing just what I want to achieve, this must be an easy task. Any app fetching data from the internet needs exactly what I'm asking for. So I must be missing something.

Using the `onResponse` is best practice for simple updates. The callback is executed on the UI-thread. This is sufficient for small apps and transient data. **This is the easy way.**

**Second part**

How to use a separate class: It already uses a separate class. The `StringRequest` is an anonymous inner class.

**Third part**

> How could it be done in a simple yet effective and reusable manner?

If you dont want to update the UI directly use a pattern like MVP or MVVM and update your model in the onRespone callback.

You will find guidance for this in the Architecture Components provided by the Framework. What you are looking for is [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html) and [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html).
For a tutorial look at the [Guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html). I'm sorry for such a general answer, but the keywords and links should cover your very general question and provide direction for your research.

**Fourth part**

> Please elaborate with examples.

No. SO is not the place for this. Look for tutorials on the [internet](https://www.google.de/search?q=design%20patterns%20java&client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNv6KqqfvZAhUDCewKHdiAB9EQ_AUICSgA&biw=1920&bih=966&dpr=1) or buy a [book](https://www.google.de/search?q=design+patterns+java&client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPlpqoqfvZAhXLzqQKHV71C_0Q_AUICygC&biw=1920&bih=966) on design patterns and come back if you have specific questions. This question is just too broad, to be answered here. Also if you want code, share what you have tried already. SO is not a 'code for me' site, although it looks like it sometimes. So look at the code in the examples and try to reproduce.

Comment: Thank's for you answer! No need to excuse!

As I said before: Part One does not solve my dilemma, as it tells me to have UI updating and data fetching mixed up. Also it does not really tell me how I could achieve it using a seperate class for the data fetching.

Part Two is indeed very general, but it points to some interesting directions.

It fascinates me, that something so common is solved so complicated...

Comment: It already uses a separate class for fetching the data. Also if you read the guide from the Architecture Components it should become clear how to use View, Model and ViewModel.

Comment: I see that the example code you gave does not follow a pattern like MVVM. For a simple example of how MVVM can be done look at this: https://github.com/erikcaffrey/People-MVVM/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/jhordan/people_mvvm (doesnt use the architecture components, but it is easier to understand how it works  in principle that way)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the repo and the tutorials! I'll definitely have a look at them!